# Endpoint Response got interchanged in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application i have many endpoint in this application. When i am hitting endpoint simultaneously JSON response from two different endpoint got interchanged.

For example:

i am hitting `/currency/list` endpoint and `/fee` endpoint and i am getting `/fee` endpoint data in `currency/list` endpoint and vice versa.

I have no idea why this happening. If anybody can suggest why happening will be helpful.

Also I am using spring security token based auth in this project

**CurrencyController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = UrlConstant.BASE_ADMIN_URI_V1)
@Api(value = "Admin Controller")
@Scope("request")
public class CurrencyController {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CurrencyController.class);

@Autowired
    private LocaleService localService;

@RequestMapping(value = UrlConstant.CURRENCY_LIST_FOR_MARKET, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getCurrencyListForMarket() {
        List<Currency> currencyList = currencyService.getCurrencyListForMarket();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String stringList = mapper.writeValueAsString(currencyList);
            logger.debug("all currency list as String: {}", stringList);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            logger.debug("error in currency list: {}", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ResponseHandler.response(HttpStatus.OK, false, localService.getMessage("currency.list.success"),
                currencyList);
    }
```

}

**AdminController.java**

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = UrlConstant.BASE_ADMIN_URI_V1)
    @Api(value = "Admin Controller")
    @Scope("request")
    public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private LocaleService localeService;

    @Autowired
    private FeeService feeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = UrlConstant.TRADING_FEES, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getTradingFees() {
        TradingFee fee = tradingFeeService.getTradingFee();
        return ResponseHandler.response(HttpStatus.OK, true,
                localeService.getMessage("admin.transaction.fees.found.success"), fee);
    }
}
```

**TokenAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        // extract token from header
        String token = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {
            AuthenticationTokenRepo authenticationTokenRepository = WebApplicationContextUtils
                    .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(httpRequest.getServletContext())
                    .getBean(AuthenticationTokenRepo.class);
            // check whether token is valid
            AuthenticationToken authToken = authenticationTokenRepository.findByToken(token);
            if (authToken != null) {
                // Add user to SecurityContextHolder
                final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        authToken.getUser(), null, new ApplicationUserDetail(authToken.getUser()).getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/user/register").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Implementing Token based authentication in this filter
        final TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenFilter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(UrlConstant.BASE_ADMIN_URI_V1 + UrlConstant.CURRENCY_LIST_FOR_MARKET);
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(UrlConstant.BASE_ADMIN_URI_V1 + UrlConstant.TRADING_FEES);

        }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUserDetail.java**

```
public class ApplicationUserDetail implements UserDetails,Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    transient User user;

    public ApplicationUserDetail(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(user.getRole().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmailId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.getIsEnabled();
    }

}
```

**More info:**  When i am printing response in my api it is correct but when i am printing it in my **Authentication filter** i got the response of fee api in my currency api so i think there is some problem between api to filter.

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: You need to show us your code - start with the Controller

Comment: Looks like you are keeping state in places where you shouldn't be keeping state.

Comment: pvpkiran, DaveH and @M.Deinum i have updated the question with the code.

Comment: For starters remove the scope from the controller. There is no state so it makes no sense to make them request scoped.

Comment: I tried removing scoped but same issue.